# Compare 2 arrays on single element in php

Tags: php, json, array-intersect

I have two arrays that look like this with many more results:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [comName] => John
        [locID] => L152145
        [locName] => Johns House

               )
)
```

What i'd like to do is compare the results but only on the locName element...here is the code i'm working with thus far.

```
$searchcode = "a url to json results"; 
$simple = file_get_contents($searchcode);
$arr = json_decode($simple , true);
```

do this for each json file then

```
 $result = array_intersect($arr, $anotherarr);
```

Ideally this would return the matching locNames from both arrays

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are a looking for is function [`array_uintersect`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php):

```
$result = array_uintersect($arr, $anotherarr, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['locName'], $b['locName']); });
```

Comment: hmm, i've never heard of this..ok, i've implement, however i'm still getting no results...manually comparing the two files I know there are a couple matches...i must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

If each locName will appear only once, then I suggest you transform your array in an associative one in the form

```
Array
(
   [Johns House] => Array
    (
        [comName] => John
        [locID] => L152145
        [locName] => Johns House

     )
)
```

This way, you'll have access to every location name using `array_keys`, and will be able to pick the locations that are present in both arrays with a simple `array_intersect` on both `array_keys`.

The simplest way to do this is to iterate over the original array filling a new one (not really efficient if you're planning to manage 10000+ elements, but negligible in other case)

```
$assocA=array();
$assocB=array();

foreach($arr as $element) {
    $assocA[$element['locName']]=$element;
}

foreach($anotherarr as $anotherelement) {
    $assocB[$anotherelement['locName']]=$anotherelement;
}

$common_locations = array_intersect(array_keys($assocA), array_keys($assocB)); // will return all locnames present in both arrays.
```

Comment: How would I go about making that transformation? seems like a clean solution, just really new to working with array..thanks